# Gatsby .cache folder in AWS Amplify Console

Tags: gatsby, aws-amplify

Recently I built a Gatsby project and deployed it on AWS Amplify using the Amplify Console and connecting my Bitbucket repo. The project grew and now it has to build 37 pages with a ton of images. I am using ‘gatsby-source-custom-api’ for the data extraction which offers image processing using ‘gatsby-image’. It also offers a way to specify if the images was changed therefore if not changed it uses the .cache to get it already optimized by the ‘gatsby-image’. 
Now the issue I face is that the .cache folder is not available between builds in AWS Amplify. Can it be stored somewhere or is there another way to use it? Now it takes a good 13 minutes to build and the major part is from image processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

*buildspec.yml*

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - mkdir -p /build-directory
      - cp -a ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/. /build-directory
      - cd /build-directory
      - yarn
  build:
    commands:
      - cd /build-directory
      - gatsby build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - cd /build-directory
      - cp -a /build-directory/. ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}
cache:
  paths:
    - 'node_modules/**/*'
    - 'public/**/*'
    - '.cache/**/*'
```

As of this writing, there is not a tidy solution. Caching the entire `.cache` directory will ultimately throw the following error:

> Failed to process image /codebuild/output/src***/src/project/.cache/gatsby-source-filesystem/***/***.png Input file is missing

As you mentioned in the comments, Gatsby assumes that the absolute path to `.cache` is consistent between builds. This is not very compatible with CodeBuild since the build directory changes for each build. Because of this, Gatsby isn't able to locate the cached files and throws an error.

For this reason, creating a consistent path and bringing the artifacts there will solve the issue. When the build is done, be sure to bring the new artifacts to the `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR` so that they can be cached for next time!

Comment: Provided buildspec is wrong for actual Amplify deployment. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'artifacts' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the .cache folder by defining it as part of the buildspec: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html#yml-specification-syntax

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Tried it. The problem is that it references folder that on the next build does not exists because the Amplify is run on Docker image and every time you want to build new image is created with different paths.