# Change .cache folder files paths from absolute to relative. Is it possible?

Tags: gatsby

Coming from my previous question [Gatsby .cache folder in AWS Amplify Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025169/gatsby-cache-folder-in-aws-amplify-console) I figured out that the docker image container that the AWS Amplify uses changes its paths on every build, but the .cache folder file paths are absolute. Is it possible to make them relative to the folder so the .cache could be distributed across builds? Sorry for the bad explanation I hope someone understands...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

*buildspec.yml*

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - mkdir -p /build-directory
      - cp -a ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/. /build-directory
      - cd /build-directory
      - yarn
  build:
    commands:
      - cd /build-directory
      - gatsby build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - cd /build-directory
      - cp -a /build-directory/. ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}
cache:
  paths:
    - 'node_modules/**/*'
    - 'public/**/*'
    - '.cache/**/*'
```

As of this writing, there is not a tidy solution. Caching the entire `.cache` directory will ultimately throw the following error:

> Failed to process image /codebuild/output/src***/src/project/.cache/gatsby-source-filesystem/***/***.png Input file is missing

Gatsby assumes that the absolute path to `.cache` is consistent between builds. This is not very compatible with CodeBuild since the build directory changes for each build. Because of this, Gatsby isn't able to locate the cached files and throws an error.

For this reason, creating a consistent path and bringing the artifacts there will solve the issue. When the build is done, be sure to bring the new artifacts to the `CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR` so that they can be cached for next time!

Comment: I will definitely try it and will get back to report if it is working fine. Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried the solution, but it throws me the same error about processing images - Input file is missing. Can you give more details about how this should work?