# AWS CodeBuild S3 cache for swift lambda

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild

So I have some aws **swift** lambdas that I deployed via `sam deploy`. That works fine.
The swift lambda looks like this: [aws-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/sessions-with-aws-sam/tree/master/swift-custom-runtime)

I am currently in the middle of building a CI/CD pipeline using Codepipeline and Codebuild. My Codebuild project executes the following `buildspec.yml` and is configured to cache to S3:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - sam build
      - sam package -t template.yml --s3-bucket bucketName --output-template-file packaged.yaml
artifacts:
  files:
    - packaged.yaml
cache:
  paths:
    - ".aws-sam/**/*"
```

To build the swift lambdas `sam build`executed the following makefile as the function in `template.yml` is set to: `BuildMethod: makefile`

Makefile:

```
### Add functions here and link them to builder-bot format MUST BE "build-FunctionResourceName in template.yaml"

build-ExpiredMediaItemProcessorLambda: builder-bot

builder-bot:
    $(eval $@PRODUCT = $(subst build-,,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    $(eval $@BUILD_DIR = $(PWD)/.aws-sam/build-$($@PRODUCT))
    $(eval $@STAGE = $($@BUILD_DIR)/lambda)
    $(eval $@ARTIFACTS_DIR = $(PWD)/.aws-sam/build/$($@PRODUCT))
    
    # prep directories
    mkdir -p $($@BUILD_DIR)/lambda $($@ARTIFACTS_DIR)

    # Compile application
    swift build --product $($@PRODUCT) -c release --build-path $($@BUILD_DIR)

    # copy deps
    ldd '/$($@BUILD_DIR)/release/$($@PRODUCT)' | grep swift | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs cp -Lv -t /$($@BUILD_DIR)/lambda

    # copy binary to stage
    cp $($@BUILD_DIR)/release/$($@PRODUCT) $($@BUILD_DIR)/lambda/bootstrap

    # copy app from stage to artifacts dir
    cp $($@STAGE)/* $($@ARTIFACTS_DIR)
```

I got the makefile from the linked aws-samples project above which I modified slightly to work on codebuild.

**Now to my question: How do I get codebuild S3 cache to work with swift lambdas?**
when I cache the `.aws-sam/**/*` folder swift cannot compile because the build paths are different due to the different build machines. The error looks like so:

```
swift build --product LambdaName -c release --build-path /codebuild/output/src409372700/src/.swift-build/build-LambdaName
33  [1/863] Compiling CSotoExpat xmltok_impl.c
34  [2/863] Compiling CSotoExpat xmltok_ns.c
35  [3/865] Compiling INIParser INIParser.swift
36  <unknown>:0: error: PCH was compiled with module cache path '.aws-sam/build-LambdaName/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/ModuleCache/1LD7OVICEM9JB', but the path is currently '/codebuild/output/src409372700/src/.aws-sam/build-LambdaName/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/ModuleCache/1LD7OVICEM9JB'
37  <unknown>:0: error: missing required module 'SwiftShims'
38  [4/865] Compiling Logging Locks.swift
39  <unknown>:0: error: PCH was compiled with module cache path '.aws-sam/build-LambdaName/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/ModuleCache/1LD7OVICEM9JB', but the path is currently '/codebuild/output/src409372700/src/.aws-sam/build-LambdaName/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/ModuleCache/1LD7OVICEM9JB'
40  <unknown>:0: error: missing required module 'SwiftShims'
```

As far as I understand this is due to the fact that swift build cannot cope with a changing or relative path.

After some digging I found [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094634/change-cache-folder-files-paths-from-absolute-to-relative-is-it-possible) which has a similar problem. I tried there solution and the swift compile error is gone but after a rebuild swift compiles the entire project again even if no code was changed.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!